# How to center a text within a rectangular shape in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment

I have the following layers:

[image: layers]

Which look like this:

[image]

Now, I want to align the text within the rounded rectangle both **horizontally** and **vertically**. However, it seems I can only do it vertically. If I tap the fifth button below:

[image: alignment issue]

That is, "Align horizontal centers", the text will be aligned to the artboard itself and not the rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: you have to select the layer you want to center and then hold CMD on Mac/ CTRL on Win + click on the target layer.

Both layers should look highlighted:

[image: layers selected]

Tapping "Align horizontal centers" will now correctly center the text within the shape and not the artboard.

Comment: Where is "Align horizontal centers"?

Comment: I honestly can't remember :) It's been 3 years. But FWIW, I now use and recommend Figma instead of Photoshop. It's much more lightweight and gets the job done more quickly.